# filter specific unicode character in SAS

Tags: unicode, sas

I need to replace a specific unicode character in SAS, exactly the U+0191 with a whitespace or blank. How can I do it by COMPRESS ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`KCOMPRESS` function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/69741/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p18bboh5zrwqw5n1kkhonig4jpwq.htm) rather than `COMPRESS` for compressing unicode characters, as it is considered safer for Unicode and DBCS environments.

However, it sounds like you actually want to `TRANSLATE`, or more accurately [`KTRANSLATE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/69741/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10atr6djv8t88n16x5xgh2l30t5.htm), which actually replaces characters with whitespace or other characters (as opposed to removing them, as `COMPRESS` does).

Here's an example:

```
data have;
  charvar = "Ƒellow Americans";
  fixed_charvar = translate(charvar,'F','Ƒ');
  kfixed_charvar= ktranslate(charvar,'F','Ƒ');
  put _all_;
run;
```

Here I convert U+0191 to a normal F; of course you can convert to space as you wish (Replace the `'F'` with whatever you want it converted to).

This will work in an instance of SAS set up in Unicode mode; if you're running in WLATIN1 or similar, you may have more difficulty, particularly with actually passing SAS the U+0191 character.